# Writing async await Angular example

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I can't understand why this async/await function that i made doesn't waiting.

```
async mustWait() {
    this.response = await this.service.mustBePrintedFirst();
    console.log('I will wait');
}

mustBePrintedFirst() {
    http.get(.....);
    console.log('I must be printed first');
}
```

Comment: You need to return a promise.

Comment: @SLaks Not just *a* promise, but *the* `http.get(…)` promise that the OP seems to want to wait for.

Comment: I just gave an example that a promise has to be returned. Please remove the downvote whoever has done.

Comment: @Bergi, May I know if I m downvoted by you?

Comment: @dileepkumarjami I downvoted the first version where you had the `http.get()` call inside the `new Promise` executor. And after your edit, the second snippet still doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi, It depends on his implementation. Anyway, he accepted the solution which means it  gave him an insight of what has to be done.

Comment: @dileepkumarjami Sure, but that doesn't mean that *I* would consider the answer useful.

Comment: @Bergi, True. All the answers may not help all the people.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Return a promise like below.

```
mustBePrintedFirst() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('whatever you want to resolve');
    console.log('I must be printed first');
   });
}
```

In your case, it would be

```
mustBePrintedFirst() {
    http.get(...).toPromise() // something ike this
}
```